# AWS PHP Curl with SSL

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, amazon-web-services, lamp

I'm trying to install the Amazon Web Services PHP SDK on my Ubuntu LAMP server. Whenever I run the compatibly check everything but cURL comes back okay. The issue I'm having is that it's reporting I don't have cURL with SSL. I uninstalled curl then installed curl-ssl with no avail.

Comment: Belongs to Serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot some packages to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev`?

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge php5-curl && \
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev curl-ssl php5-curl
```

Then restart server:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

This question should be on maybe serverfault.com/ubuntu

Comment: Worked, your awesome. From now on I'll try to make sure post my questions in the appropriate forum.

Comment: Ok. This already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue with my EC-2 faced the issue with the above answer. Then I found a command

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

This help me fix the issue.

for more reference

https://askubuntu.com/questions/530323/how-to-make-curl-and-php-available-when-installed-from-xampp?newreg=720483ecd77b4d0aaa09da29c79de8a3